# PHP MySQL STR_TO_DATE

Tags: php, mysql

For some reasons my date is saved in a varchar field in my mysql database table. It's in the format e.g. 06.04.2022 15:20:00. I would like to execute the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Files WHERE Aktenzeichen = '55/22' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`Uhrzeit`,'%d.%M.%Y %H:%i:%s') DESC
```

It's not sorting the values correctly. Any hints?

Kindest regards!

Comment: If you intend to regularly sort by date, it would really be a good idea to have an actual datetime column with an index. If you must have the other format for some reasons, then add an extra column where you have a SQL-native time format. What happens if you run `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`Uhrzeit`,'%d.%M.%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM Files`, are you getting what you expect?

Comment: can you share your value? which one you want to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, M stands for Month as name

and test you can always run a simple select.

Still, this will always cost a lot of time and resources, so save the date in a mysql format always

> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('06.04.2022 15:20:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE('06.04.2022 15:20:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') |
> | :----------------------------------------------------- |
> | 2022-04-06 15:20:00                                    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eaed21b96aed1df098976cafefc189ce)*

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(`Uhrzeit`, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s") was the correct one

Comment: i know but the query only works with a string and i would have been forced to make a table inert data, and you can easily adept it as you have shown